# How to return to URL stored in cookie

Tags: javascript

I've set up an infinite scroll on our category page. When a user clicks load more, the current page URL is stored as a cookie.

when the user then clicks onto a product and hits the back button I would like them to return to the same point.

How would I set the back button to go back to the URL stored in the cookie?

### Current JS :

```
$(document).on('click', '.page-next a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = $(this),
        loadparent = self.parents('.ajax-load');

    setTimeout(function () { $(loadparent).fadeOut(); }, 700);

    $('.ajaxLoaderOverlay').addClass('show');

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.mid-content').append(data);
            $('.ajaxLoaderOverlay').removeClass('show');
        }
    });

    var thisCookie = $(this).parent().data('href');
    setCookie('listingPerRow', thisCookie, '30');
});
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean 'back button'? A button you've created, or the browser's back button?

Comment: @FZs browser back button

Comment: The browser's back button's behaviour  is something, that you unlikely able to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution would be to have the "Load more" button change the url to a link to a certain element (`www.example.com/#id`). Then, the back button will scroll to that part of the page without any need for additional JavaScript:

```
var place = 0;
...
location.href = location.href.slice("#")[0] + "#load-" + place++;
```